# What is the use of Context to start an activity in Android?

Tags: android

When starting another activity, the method `startActivity(someintent)` is used, that intent, at the same time, contains the parameters `this` for context and a class object.

What is the use of the `this` parameter, given that the context is already known since the activity itself is a subclass of context? And, given that I create an intent as:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,someclass.class);
```

Am I only able to use the method `startActivity` when inside `this` context specified when creating `myIntent`. In other words, I can't use `startActivity` with the same intent from another activity.

Comment: `this` means the instance of the class which in your case the activity.

Comment: Are you asking why the API designers made you supply the `Context` instead of just assuming `this`?

Comment: Sorry, that was not my question.

Comment: Yes, Kevin. And what purpose does this serve? Is it to set a restriction on which activities/ contexts can startActivity with the same intent?

Answer (score 1):

Several reasons:

1. You are not required to use `this` as the context when creating a new `Intent` in an activity. (You might, for instance, create a `ContextThemeWrapper` to apply a separate theme.)
2. The `Intent` constructor can be called from outside an `Activity`. In any event, the `Intent` constructor has no way of knowing what object is calling the constructor (if any—it could even be called from a static context).
3. There are other uses for an `Intent` besides calling `startActivity()`.

Comment: @SpiderMan - like requesting functionality from a service or passing a result back from a sub-activity.

Comment: In case I do use it in a starActivity method,  does the activity calling the method has to be the same as the "this" used for the intent constructor? What permissions have to be taken into account?

Comment: @FelipeCalderon - Only those `Intent` constructors that accept a specific component class require a context. It can be any context in the application package that implements the class passed as the second argument. So you might as well use `this` if you're calling the constructor from something that's a `Context` in the application. There are no permission issues involved in the choice.

Comment: What Intent constructors accept specific components? What do you mean by that, sorry?

Comment: @FelipeCalderon - The constructors that also accept a `Class` argument that specifies a specific component that will be the target of the `Intent`. There are six `Intent` constructors and only two of them accept `Context` and `Class` arguments. Consult [the API docs for `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) or the Guide topic [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) for more info.